# access to keychain error when try to login to appcenter from Xcode Cloud

Tags: macos, appcenter, xcode-cloud, ci-scripts

this is some part of my script for uploading the app to appcenter from Xcode Cloud:

```
  1. $brew install npm
  2. $npm install -g appcenter-cli
  3. $appcenter login --token [my-token]
  4. $appcenter distribute release -f $CI_AD_HOC_SIGNED_APP_PATH/MyApp.ipa -g Collaborator --app UserName/App --release-notes-file releaseNote.txt
```

but I got this error at 3:

```
Error: Could not add password to keychain: security: SecKeychainItemCreateFromContent (<default>): User interaction is not allowed.
```

how can I add the password to the Xcode Cloud keychain?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to save your password and login to the app center in Xcode Cloud
`appcenter distribute release` has an option for adding a token

I removed `appcenter login --token [my-token]`

and token added to `appcenter distribute release -f $CI_AD_HOC_SIGNED_APP_PATH/MyApp.ipa -g Collaborator --app UserName/App --release-notes-file releaseNote.txt --token [my-token]`